# Delete numerically equivalent raster layer in R

Tags: r, terra, duplicates

When I download a raster from a WMS, I get three **numerically identical layers**. Is there a method with the `terra` package to find and remove equal layers?

I could keep only the first layer, but I'm also downloading RGB raster which doesn't need this treatment.

Here is how to get the raster from R :

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
library(tmap)

dsn <- tempfile(fileext = ".tif")

url <- paste0("WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?",
              "VERSION=1.3.0&",
              "REQUEST=GetMap&",
              "LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&",
              "CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&",
              "BBOX=-62.952807692,-13.007809422,45.304315325,51.105279680")

gdal_utils("warp",
           source = url,
           destination = dsn,
           options = c("-t_srs", "EPSG:2154",
                       "-te_srs", "EPSG:2154",
                       "-te", "148121.3", "6769530.0", "154597.0", "6773354.1",
                       "-tr", "10", "10",
                       "-overwrite"))

rast <- rast(dsn)
rast

qtm(rast)
```

**EDIT :**

**The method I found is to create new raster witch is the difference between layer one and two then check that minmax is close to zero (see ?terra::all.equal example). It works, but can be quite computationally intensive for large rasters.**

```
rm_equal_layers <- function(rast){
   
   diff_rast <- rast[[1]] - rast[[2]]
   duplicate_layers <- all(abs(minmax(diff_rast) < 1e-7))
   
   if (duplicate_layers){
      return(rast[[1]])
   }
   
   return(rast)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have duplicate rasters reflected by duplicated names you can create an index using `duplicated` and `which`. Here is an example where the n object would be the names of your raster ie., `names(x)` would be substituted for n.

```
( n <- c(paste0("rast",1:5),"rast1", "rast3") )
( dup.idx <- which(duplicated(n)) )
```

You can then use the index to remove the duplicate raster(s) from the stack.

```
x <- x[[-dup.idx]]
```

However, it is never that simple since you can not, in fact, have exactly duplicated names. If they are duplicated R will automatically append a .1, .2, etc... As such you can create an vector representing the names in the raster object, split them to remove the appending characters and then apply the above code.

```
( n <- c(paste0("rast",1:5),"rast1.1", "rast3.1") )
( n <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(n, "[.]"), function(x) x[1])) )
( dup.idx <- which(duplicated(n)) )
```

Now, if you are referring to equality in the rasters (rasters that are numerically equivalent) that is a different thing entirely and it would be prudent for you to clarify this.

Comment: Thank you . You are right i'm referring to numerically equivalent rasters, I will change my post to clarify it.

Answer (score 1):

**Try the code below and please let me know the result. Thank you.**

```
library(sf)
library(terra)

dsn <- "C:/Users/PAUL/Documents/temp.tif"

url <- paste0("WMS:https://wxs.ign.fr/altimetrie/geoportail/r/wms?",
              "VERSION=1.3.0&",
              "REQUEST=GetMap&",
              "LAYERS=ELEVATION.ELEVATIONGRIDCOVERAGE.HIGHRES&",
              "CRS=IGNF:WGS84G&",
              "BBOX=-62.952807692,-13.007809422,45.304315325,51.105279680")

gdal_utils("warp",
           source = url,
           destination = dsn,
           options = c("-t_srs", "EPSG:2154",
                       "-te_srs", "EPSG:2154",
                       "-te", "148121.3", "6769530.0", 
                       "154597.0", "6773354.1",
                       "-tr", "10", "10",
                       "-overwrite"))

rast <- rast("C:/Users/PAUL/Documents/temp.tif")

# Function to remove duplicate layers while keeping the first occurrence
remove_duplicate_layers <- function(x) {
  layers_seen <- c()
  keep <- logical(nlyr(x))
  for (i in 1:nlyr(x)) {
    layer_name <- names(x)[i]
    if (!(layer_name %in% layers_seen)) {
     layers_seen <- c(layers_seen, layer_name)
     keep[i] <- TRUE
    }
  }
  x[keep]
}

# Apply the function to remove duplicate layers
rast_final <- remove_duplicate_layers(rast)

rast_final
plot(rast_final)
```

**In this updated code, it defines the function remove_duplicate_layers() to iterate through the layers of the raster object, keeping track of the layer names that have been seen. If a layer name has not been seen before, it should mark it for keeping (as setting the corresponding element of keep to TRUE). And can keep the first occurrence of each layer, effectively removing duplicates.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you. It works but as Jeffrey Evans highlight, I'm looking to remove numerically equivalent rasters. I'm going to change my post accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

**To remove identical layers from a raster stack in the terra package, you can use the unique() function.**

---

**Example code:**

```
library(terra)

# Assuming you have a raster stack named 'rast'

# Check if the first layer is RGB
is_rgb <- attr(rast[[1]], "RGB")

if (is_rgb) {
  # If the first layer is RGB, keep it as it is
  final_rast <- rast[1]
} else {
  # If the first layer is not RGB, remove identical layers
  unique_rast <- unique(rast)

  # Check if all layers are identical
  if (nlyr(unique_rast) == 1) {
    # If all layers are identical, keep the first layer
    final_rast <- unique_rast[1]
  } else {
    # If there are unique layers, retain them
    final_rast <- unique_rast
  }
}

# Display the resulting raster stack
plot(final_rast)
```

---

**Explanation:**

It checks if the first layer of the raster stack (rast) is an RGB layer using the attr() function. If it is, it keeps the first layer as it is since RGB layers do not require the removal of identical layers.

If the first layer is not an RGB layer, it uses the unique() function to remove duplicated layers and assigns the result to unique_rast. Then, it checks if all layers in unique_rast are identical. If they are, it keeps the first layer; otherwise, it retains the unique layers.

Finally, the resulting raster stack (final_rast) is plotted.

**If you have further question, please let me know.**

Comment: Thanks, I tried you're method but there is several problem. First one, I don't have "RGB" attributes with raster from my example. The second one is that `unique()` doesn't work for removing duplicate raster, as the documentation said `This method returns the unique values in a SpatRaste`.

Comment: I've updated a code, please try it and let me know.